# Grey Screen when using CreateDesktop, no taskbar or icon showing

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to develop an application that creates a new desktop, and I want this desktop to be usable, like to have icons, taskbar... So to do that, I used the `CreateDesktop()` function, but the newly created desktop is just a grey screen. Even after executing `explorer.exe` in that desktop, it doesn't work, there is still a grey screen, like this:

[image]

(I also figured, if I try to open a file with that explorer, the file is not open in that new desktop but the old one)

I used this GitHub project, made in C++, and adapted it for Delphi:

https://github.com/MalwareTech/CreateDesktop/

This is my code:

```pascal
function CreateHiddenDesktop(desktopname : string) : THandle;
var
  pi : TProcessInformation;
  si : TStartupInfoA;
  hidden_Desktop,original_desktop : THandle;
begin
  //Creating a new desktop
  hidden_Desktop := CreateDesktop('hdtest',nil,nil,0,GENERIC_ALL,nil);
  //Saving handle of current desktop
  original_desktop := GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadID());

  SetThreadDesktop(hidden_desktop);

  //Executing explorer.exe in the new desktop
  si := Default(TStartupInfoA);
  si.cb := sizeof(si);
  si.lpDesktop := 'hdtest';

  if not CreateProcessA(
        'C:\Windows\System32\explorer.exe',         
        nil, 
        nil,                
        nil,               
        False,
        0,
        nil,                
        nil,        
        si,                 //Startup Info
        pi                 //Process Info
  ) then
    MessageBox(0, PChar('error when creating process inside the desktop'), PChar(''), 0);

  SetThreadDesktop(original_desktop);

  Result := hidden_desktop;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  hidden_Desktop,original_desktop : THandle;
  msg : TMSG;
begin
  hidden_Desktop := CreateHiddenDesktop('hdtest');
  original_desktop := GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());

  MessageBox(0, PChar('Entering hidden desktop'), PChar('HVNC'), 0);

  SetThreadDesktop(hidden_desktop);
  SwitchDesktop(hidden_desktop);

  //If the keys CTR + ALT + E are pressed we go back to the original desktop
  if RegisterHotKey(0,1,MOD_CONTROL + MOD_ALT + MOD_NOREPEAT,ord('E')) then
  begin
    while(GetMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0)) do
    begin
      if msg.message = WM_HOTKEY then
      begin
        SwitchDesktop(original_desktop);
        break;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  CloseHandle(hidden_desktop);
end;
```

Comment: The translation of `%windir%` to `C:\Windows\System32` doesn't look right.

Comment: Indeed, you cannot assume that `explorer.exe` has path `C:\Windows\System32\explorer.exe`. On the majority of systems, this is wrong and should be `C:\Windows\explorer.exe`. But hardcoding this path is also wrong. For instance, a particular user may have installed Windows on their D: drive.

Comment: Yeah I also tried with 'C:\Windows\explorer.exe' but when I do that explorer.exe doesn't even launch on the new desktop, it appears on the original.

Comment: Well, if your system doesn't have a file with path `C:\Windows\System32\explorer.exe`, trying to start it will not work on *any* desktop.

Comment: no the explorer.exe file exists in both C:\Windows\ and C:\Windows\System32 folders for me at least.

Comment: This works on Windows 7 for me and fails identically on Windows 10. However I had to launch Notepad since Explorer didn't work on Windows 7 at all.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution I found is that, when using `SetThreadDesktop()`, I needed to create another thread before, because my application had a GUI. But it didn't work until I re-started my computer.

Turned out, it was because the Delphi application was executed as an Admnistrator. When I executed it in the user context, it worked.

I lost several days of my life on this...